# Using MarkerOptions in Google Map Android, how to display image in dialog box?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am working on Google Maps Android API. I have used MarkerOptions in which I am displaying Icon as a PIN, Distance and Title from the following code. Now I want to display an image in my dialog box. Image is given below which I want it to be.

```
final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                    JSONObject jPlace = arrayOfPlaces.getJSONObject(i);

                    if (!jPlace.isNull("title")) {
                        place = jPlace.getString("title");
                    }
                    if (!jPlace.isNull("urlhtml")) {
                        icon = jPlace.getString("urlhtml");
                    }
                    if (!jPlace.isNull("id")) {
                        distance = jPlace.getString("id");
                    }
                    if (!jPlace.isNull("distance")) {
                        distance = jPlace.getString("distance");
                    }

                    longitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("location").getString("lon");
                    latitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    markerOptions.title(place);
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_x));

                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions).setSnippet("Distance "+distance);
                    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions).showInfoWindow();
```

Current Image:

[image: Current Image which i am getting right now]

Desired Image:

[image: This is the image which i want]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Create custom InfoWindowAdapter

```
 public class MyCustomAdapterForItems implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View myContentsView;

    MyCustomAdapterForItems() {
        myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.map_info_window_dialog, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentsView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtHeader));
        TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentsView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtAddress));
        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) myContentsView
                .findViewById(R.id.mStoreImage);
        final ProgressBar mProgress = (ProgressBar) myContentsView
                .findViewById(R.id.mProgress);

        tvTitle.setTypeface(mTyFaceHelvetica);
        tvSnippet.setTypeface(mTyFaceHelvetica);
        if (clickedClusterItem != null) {
            tvTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(clickedClusterItem
                    .getmOfferTitle()));
            tvSnippet.setText(Html.fromHtml(clickedClusterItem
                    .getmOfferDesc()));
            Log.e("Coupon Image URL : ",
                    "" + clickedClusterItem.getmCouponImageURL());

            mImageLoader.displayImage(
                    clickedClusterItem.getmCouponImageURL(), mImageView,
                    Utils.Options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri,
                                View view) {
                            mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri,
                                View view, FailReason failReason) {
                            mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                            mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });

            // ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(
            // clickedClusterItem.getmCouponImageURL(), mImageView,
            // Utils.Options);
        }
        return myContentsView;
    }
}
```

Set custom adapter to Googlemap

```
google_map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyCustomAdapterForItems());
```